# Change an attribute of a function inside its own body?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, decorator

I'm attempting to create a function that keeps count of the times it has been called, and I want the information to stay inside the function itself.
I tried creating a wrapper like so:

```
def keep_count(f):
    f.count = 0
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
        f(*args, **kwargs)
        f.count += 1
    return wrapped_f

@keep_count
def test_f(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
```

I thought it'd work, but I got an `AttributeError` saying `'function' object has no attribute 'count'`.

I already figured the problem: It's because the decorator sets my `test_f` to equal to the `wrapped_f` (defined inside the `keep_count` decorator), and I'm increasing the count of the original `f`, which is no longer used since `test_f` refers to the new function.

Is there a way to do this without too much of hacking?

Comment: Why not use a class? That's kind of what a class is for -- creating a stateful context to run functions in

Comment: @AdamSmith Since python functions are objects, can't they maintain state as well?

Comment: @wegry sure they can. You can also use a pair of pliers to nail two boards together :)

Comment: Actually, that code works just fine on Python 3.4.

Comment: @JonasWielicki I do have 3.4, doesn't work. When I call `test_f()`, it increases the count of `f`, but `test_f` refers to the `wrapped_f`.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen There is not AttributeError though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set the attribute on `wrapped_f` instead of `f`.  This requires you to set the initial `count` after defining the function, but that's no big deal:

```
def keep_count(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
        f(*args, **kwargs)
        wrapped_f.count += 1
    wrapped_f.count = 0
    return wrapped_f
```

Then with your decorated function:

```
>>> test_f()
() {}
>>> test_f.count
1
>>> test_f()
() {}
>>> test_f.count
2
```

This works because `wrapped_f` is a local variable inside `keep_count`.  Since the body of `wrapped_f` contains a reference to `wrapped_f`, it gets a closure allowing `wrapped_f` to access itself.

Comment: Wow, I've always thought you can't use a function inside of itself... Then again, I've been using recursive functions for as long as I remember, can't see why couldn't I do this O.o Just have had a misconception of some kind. Well, thanks for the answer, I guess you learn something new in the old stuff every day! :)

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: You can, more or less, but you have to be careful about it, because the name lookups happen at different times.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks... :) I'll keep digging into it, will accept as soon as I can.