# Wrapping a function hides its attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, wrapper, python-decorators

This is continuation to my previous question [Change an attribute of a function inside its own body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909592/change-an-attribute-of-a-function-inside-its-own-body).

If I've wrapped a function so that it keeps a count of the times it has been called using the following decorator:

```
def keep_count(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
        f(*args, **kwargs)
        wrapped_f.count += 1
    wrapped_f.count = 0
    return wrapped_f
```

And then I want to wrap it again with something else:

```
def decorator2(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def fn_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if my_condition(fn):
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return fn_wrapper

test_f = decorator2(test_f)
```

I can no longer access the function's `count` attribute as I'm hoping to.
The current value of the `count` attribute gets copied via `@wraps(fn)`, but if I call the function again, the count will increment inside the original function, but the new value won't get copied to the new decorated function.

```
>>> test_f()
() {}
>>> test_f.count
1
>>> test_f = decorator2(test_f)
>>> test_f.count  # The 1 gets copied here
1
>>> test_f()  # Only the inner function's count increments...
() {}
>>> test_f.count  # Still one, tho it should be two
1
```

Is there any solution to this?
Like "constantly" rewrapping, or something better?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Updated... And yeah I'm aware of that, I'm basically asking how to share them :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`functools.wraps()` only *copies across* attributes. When you then increment the counter on the wrapped function, you are assigning a *new* integer value to the attribute, and the wrapper will still reference the old value.

Instead of having `wraps` copy across attributes, have it copy across the whole `__dict__` attribute of the function:

```
from functools import wraps, WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS

def decorator2(fn):
    @wraps(fn, assigned=WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS + ('__dict__',), updated=())
    def fn_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if my_condition(fn):
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return fn_wrapper
```

Now the wrapped function `fn` and the `fn_wrapper` objects share the mutable `__dict__` namespace dictionary and any changes made to that dictionary are visible in both functions.

`assigned` is the sequence of attributes to copy across (it normally copies things like the docstring, the function name and the module name), and `updated` is the sequence of attributes that should be treated like dictionaries, where those dictionaries are updated from the wrapped function. The latter is normally set to `__dict__`, but now that we copy across the whole object, we no longer need to update it from the original.

Comment: Ahh looks like the solution I was hoping for :) What does the `updated=()` do?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: updated the answer to explain what the two arguments mean.